# Reduce the padding inside a spinner android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm new to android development.Basically my question is how do I change the padding within a spinner so that the text is more compact and can therefore fit more values on the screen.

I have thought about using a slider, however I because there is such a wide range the value could be (1-20000) I wanted to enforce some restriction so selected lower numbers is easier.

Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write s custom Spinner Adapter and override getView to write your own view. I had written some [sample code](https://github.com/ravivyas84/AndroidSpinnerHint) for another similar question which might help.

Comment: As a follow up question @Ravi,when saving the selected item's id and then re-reading there seems to be a mismatch in types.
`//To get the current selected Id (returns Long)   (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.distance_spinner)).getSelectedItemId();`

`//To read back in (expects int)
distance_spinner.setSelection(distToInt);`